# '<class 'KeyError'>' ("the cache has no package named 'wine-staging-I386'")

Tags: package-management, updates, update-manager

I'm getting the following error:

[image]

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
# partial output
Reading package lists... Done 
W: GPG error: https://download.01.org trusty Release:
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: 
NO_PUBKEY A902DDA375E52366
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease 
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease 
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease 
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease 
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com' 
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com' 
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com' 
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg Could not resolve 'dl.google.com' 
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg Could not resolve 'extras.ubuntu.com' 
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

[Full output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10564144/)

Comment: Please open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get update`..then edit our question and add the output..

Comment: it tells me I need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links. how should I go about posting it?

Comment: [save here](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and give the link in the comment.

Comment: I have similar issues every time I run `sudo apt-get update`. However, the error message disappear just after `sudo apt-get upgrade` (or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`)

Comment: I keep getting this as well, after I get over it with the terminal the same error keeps coming up again. Seems an ubuntu-issue with wine.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after trying a number of things I have finally figured it out:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A902DDA375E52366
```

then I ran

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

BUt ended up getting the same error as before:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
wine-staging wine-staging-amd64 wine-staging-i386:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

Then I clicked on the error shown in the screenshot attached above -> show updates -> and updates went through okay. Hope adding that key was the right thing to do....? Also, does anyone know WHY did I start getting this error (so I can avoid this in the future)?